# Rails model not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I just created two tables from a Rails migration. One for `ShippingLabel` and another for a model named `Shippo`. The migration runs successfully, it creates a table in Postgres correctly, it even looks like it recognizes Shippo as a constant. However its not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base like it should for Shippo.

**shippo.rb**

```
class Shippo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and

**shipping_label.rb**

```
class ShippingLabel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :device_purchase

end
```

When I run `ShippingLabel < ActiveRecord::Base` I get `true`. When I run `Shippo < ActiveRecord::Base` in the console I get `nil`.

Comment: the table names are `shippos` and `shipping_labels` in Postgres

Comment: try to reload your rails console.

Comment: @llya I've tried `reload!` and exiting out of it multiple times, no luck

Comment: Could it be a problem with the ActiveRecord pluralization logic? Or the fact that the two new tables have the same first 5 letters? This is weird issue.

Comment: Class inheritance has nothing to do with migrations or the db. Its just plain ruby.

Comment: I think I found the problem. 'Shippo' is the same name of a gem I have installed https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-ruby-client

Comment: ActiveRecord just looks at the database schema and adds accessors and stuff for the columns. It does not modify the inheritance of your model classes. I would try setting up a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the error is probably just a misstake somewhere like for example you are plastering the constant `Shippo`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use class.superclass on an **instance** of an object to determine the superclass.

In Rails console:

```
shippo = Shippo.new #shippo is an instance of the class Shippo
shippo.class.superclass
```